# jQuery number of inputs in a form

Tags: jquery, forms, size

I have a form and I want to know the number of inputs in a form.

I am trying to access it like this:

`alert($(this).parents("form").(':input').size());`

Where this function is called from a button click in the form, using `.parents()` to get the correct form from the page and I need a handler to the input such as using `$('input').size()` but for a specific form.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: The `:input` selector selects all controls in a `<form>` including buttons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a count of the number of inputs in that `form` element, you can do:

```
$(this).parents("form").find('input').length
```

---

References:

- [jQuery find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)
- [jQuery length](http://api.jquery.com/length/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).parents("form:input").length
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  alert($(this).parents('form :input').length);
```